# Pycharm: No code completion from dataclasses and added attributes

Tags: python, pycharm

I'm having trouble with code completion on Pycharm with dataclasses.

Say I have the following datatypes `my_datatype.py`

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Color:
    name: str


@dataclass
class Point:
    x: int
    y: int
    z: float
```

The following data definition `my_data.py`

```
from my_datatypes import Color, Point

# P1
P1 = Point(1, 2, 3)
P1.RED = Color('red')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(P1.RED)
```

Here code completion works fine, I have the RED attribute :
[image: Code completion OK]

But when I import my file `my_data.py` on another Python file, I'm not seeing the completion for the RED attribute :
[image: Code completion KO]

Anybody might know why ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: PyCharm has the exact same behaviour for *any* class. Inference outside of the current module (scope?) only takes into account static information.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi thank you for your response. Does it mean I'm stuck with this kind of behavior, or is there any workaround ?

Comment: I doubt there is a workaround. Tracking arbitrary information is *hard*, so I would assume that PyCharm *deliberately* does not do it across modules. If you need additional attributes, why not properly add them in the class?

Comment: Okay, indeed I can see the issue here. I'm not adding them properly into the class because the *points* in my example are automatically generated from an .xml file into a pure Python file. I'm doing it this way to have code completion with PyCharm.